# C# datagridview crashing randomly in same loop process

Tags: c#, datagridview, crash

I am having a problem in Datagridview: it is crashing randomly in the same loop process. Sometimes after running for 2 or 3 hours, sometimes after 5 mins. There is no issue with processor memory or resources, I checked on multiple machines: i3, i7, servers etc)

My code is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.NewRowIndex].Clone();

                row.Cells[0].Value = i;
                row.Cells[1].Value = i;
                row.Cells[2].Value = i;
                row.Cells[3].Value = i;
                row.Cells[4].Value = i;
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
                if (i % 2 == 0 && i >= 0)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                }
                else
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0 && i >= 0)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }

            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

        }


    }
```

Timer set at 10 secs (Interval: 10000)

It is crashing at random time intervals...5 min or 2 hour or 3 hour continuous running.

try catch not working....

On adding:

```
static void Main()
        {
            Application.ThreadException += ThreadException;
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledException;

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        private static void ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.ToString());
        }

        private static void UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
        }
```

It is showing this error message:

```
"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\r\n   
        at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell.PaintPrivate(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, Int32 rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, Object formattedValue, String errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts, Boolean computeContentBounds, Boolean computeErrorIconBounds, Boolean paint)\r\n   
        at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell.Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, Int32 rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, Object value, Object formattedValue, String errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.PaintWork(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, Int32 rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow.PaintCells(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle rowBounds, Int32 rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates rowState, Boolean isFirstDisplayedRow, Boolean isLastVisibleRow, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)\r\n   
        at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow.Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle rowBounds, Int32 rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates rowState, Boolean isFirstDisplayedRow, Boolean isLastVisibleRow)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PaintRows(Graphics g, Rectangle boundingRect, Rectangle clipRect, Boolean singleHorizontalBorderAdded)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PaintGrid(Graphics g, Rectangle gridBounds, Rectangle clipRect, Boolean singleVerticalBorderAdded, Boolean singleHorizontalBorderAdded)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)\r\n   
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)\r\n   
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)\r\n   
        at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)"
```

Not getting anywhere on finding the issue and resolving it...(stuck from past 10 days).

Comment: I am using timer & backgroundworker........Could it be possible that both (if running on separate threads) are conflicting with each other. Even if I am using "backgroundWorker1.IsBusy" before starting backgroundWorker1 thread.

Comment: I have tried lock >> still crashing;

Comment: I have written logs & state of "backgroundWorker1.IsBusy" at all instances....no issue found(2 instances of backgroundWorker1 not running simultaneously)...logs reaching till the end of backgroundWorker1...still crashing